# Intellij can't find JDK

Tags: java

I couldn't find any other answers on StackOverflow on this. I just installed Intellij, and it can't find my JDK for some reason.

Here's what I did:

Install Java JDK 9.0.1

1. Open Intellij
2. Open new project
3. Clicked "new" button beside the find SDK.
4. Found my java 9.0.1 bin folder under Program Files. It didn't work.
5. Tried java 8.something folder under Program Files (86x). It didn't work.
6. Went into advanced system settings and edited the path variable to the new java 9.0.1 bin as per (https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud282/lessons/8186340458/concepts/900a2a40-3921-4604-a258-c11ec355003c).
7. Now I can't even open Intellij. It just says: Cannot start under Java 1.7.0_79-b15: Java 1.8 or later is required.

Note: I also have Android studio and Netbean and both have been working no problem. Heard Intellij was better than Netbean so tried using it for the first time.

Comment: Select not "bin" folder but upper folder, without "/bin".

Comment: I would have tried to delete all JDKs except 8.151. Delete Intellij (what's version 3?) and then download latest 2017.3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you do not need to select the bin folder just select the path where Java is installed. Go to project structure (ctrl+alt+shift+s) and add new sdk refer to below pic for details.
[image]

Answer (score -2):

my solution was to reinstall and the path has already been received:

**sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk**

the path that I put after was:

/usr/lib/jvm/